# Low frame rate on JS and CSS animations

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions, frame-rate

So, as you can see in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/filipetedim/Lfed8wbh/1/), I'm doing a bounce animation in native JavaScript, which is intended to be a floating cloud.

The problem is I want to make it bounce up and down for 10px only, yet doing so makes it look like it's on a low frame rate, and I'd like it to be more smooth.

I've found out that increasing the px amount from 10 to 20 increases its smoothness, I suppose because it's a higher distance and it runs it faster. I've kind of ran out of ideas on what it could be.

```
elem.style.top = elem.offsetTop - 10 + "px";
```

The above code is the one used for the achieved result, and it is because the applied "left" property is in a class, rather than the element itself, therefore the use of 'offsetTop' is needed.

**EDIT**

Using transfom I was able to make it smoother:

```
elem.style.webkitTransform = 'translateY(-10px)';
```

But the question remains and I want to know how to do it in native JavaScript.

HTML

```
<div id='cloud' class='style'></div>
```

CSS

```
#cloud{
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: green;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
       -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
         -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

.style{
    left: 150px;
    top: 50px;
}
```

JS

```
var bounce = true;
var cloud = document.getElementById('cloud');
var interval = setInterval(animate(cloud), 1000);

function animate(elem) {
    return function () {
        if (bounce) {
            elem.style.top = elem.offsetTop - 10 + "px";
            bounce = false;
        } else {
            elem.style.top = elem.offsetTop + 10 + "px";
            bounce = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you not using css transitions (http://codepen.io/dodozhang21/pen/siKtp) or JS exist framework (https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/effect/easing.html)?

Comment: To answer the second, because I want to learn how to do it myself, I won't re-invent the wheel, but I want to know I'm able to make one. The first one, I've never used SCSS and I'd like to get this going with JS events (I'm practicing JS).
I've tried using the transform tho, and it works wonderfully (although I'd prefer JS like said), but it resets when I'm moving my mouse, dunno why.

Comment: If you're already using transform, you should follow @MoshFeu's advice and do it all in CSS. If you want to use pure JS, then do it with pure JS and even use a canvas element while you're at it, but don't mix n' match CSS and JS that way or you'll end up –as you experienced –with poor performance:

The jittering on the animation it's because the browser doesn't sync the "1 second" between the CSS rendering and the Javascript execution, you have no control on that matter.

Comment: as @fixmycode suggested, choose between CSS and JS. Here is an example in pure JS using rAF: http://jsfiddle.net/Lfed8wbh/5/

Comment: Wow, that's a good solution Tahir, but I fail to understand really. Coulkd you update that jsfiddle to contain some comments? Never used requestanim before, and how can i make it go slower?

Comment: @Ted: take a look at this **[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lfed8wbh/6/)** with annotated comments.

Comment: @Ted: and read **[this](https://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/)** on `requestAnimationFrame` API.

Comment: Cheers homie! I'll take a read there!

Answer (score 0):

You can set a higher number as the change in offset(200 instead of 10), set a longer duration for transition(20s instead of 1s) and break the transition using a shorter interval for setInterval (400 instead of 1000). You can play with different values of these three and get the best result.

see fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Lfed8wbh/4/

```
#cloud {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: green;
    -webkit-transition: top 20s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: top 20s ease-out;
    -o-transition: top 20s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: top 20s ease-out;
}
.style {
    left: 150px;
    top: 50px;
}
```

.

```
var bounce = true;
var cloud = document.getElementById('cloud');
var top = cloud.offsetTop;
var interval = setInterval(animate(cloud), 400);

function animate(elem) {
    return function () {
        if (bounce) {
            elem.style.top = elem.offsetTop - 200 + "px";
            bounce = false;
        } else {
            elem.style.top = elem.offsetTop + 200 + "px";
            bounce = true;
        }
    }
}
```

haven't tested completely, but you can try this.

Answer (score 0):

Posting my comment as a solution as it may help:

**Snippet:**

```js
window.requestAnimFrame = (function() {
  return window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || function(callback) {
    window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
  };
})();

var isGoingDown = true;
var cloud = document.getElementById('cloud');
var max = 60; // max position you want to reach to (in px), has to be higher than min
var min = 50; // min position you want to react to (in px), has to be lower than max
var increment = 1; // speed, with 1 being normal, 2 being twice the speed, 0.5 being half and so on ... has to be within the range of (max - min)

cloud.style.top = '50px'; // initially apply the style on the element so it is easily get later

requestAnimFrame(loop);

function loop() {
  requestAnimFrame(loop);

  if (parseFloat(cloud.style.top) >= max) {
    isGoingDown = false;
  } else if (parseFloat(cloud.style.top) <= min) {
    isGoingDown = true;
  }

  if (isGoingDown) {
    cloud.style.top = (parseFloat(cloud.style.top) + increment) + 'px';
  } else {
    cloud.style.top = (parseFloat(cloud.style.top) - increment) + 'px';
  }
}
```

```css
#cloud {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
}
.style {
  left: 150px;
  top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="cloud" class="style"></div>
```

Comments included in the snippet itself. Hope this helps.